# Convert iOS app to 64 bit architecture getting error and warnings

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, xcode

I have developed iOS app. It is working fine on 32 bit devices, but App Store needs to support 64 bit compulsory. so I have added arm64 to architecture, and I'm getting type citing error..

1. cast from pointer to smaller type int loses information..

   ```
   r14 = (int)((byte*)type - (int)mem_ds);
   ```
2. many same warnings: Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'long long' to 'int'

You  can see it in screen shot:

[image: This is my screen shot having error]

Answer (score 1):

As said in the doc (see [64-Bit Transition Guide for Cocoa Touch](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html)) use the special `uintptr_t` type to avoid truncation.

Comment: Thank you so much for quick reply... I m completely new in this so can you tell me how to use uintptr_t.. thank you so much

Comment: Use it as a replacement for `int` when you need to store pointer values in integers. `r14` should be of type `uintptr_t`.